# How to set user's default GID on login

Tags: permissions, login, groups

I am trying to set up a computer with a shared document directory for my untech parents. In order to do this, I need them to default to a specific primary group I have created for this purpose, which defines the group ownership of the shared directory. So of course I set that with usermod, and everything is peachy-from the terminal. If I su to that user in the terminal, after entering the password, and 'id', it shows me that they are operating as the group I specified, and I can write files as expected.

```
> id
   uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(sharers) groups=1003(sharers),1001(fred)
```

However, when I login from the dashboard, open a terminal, and 'id', it shows that their default group is their own login name. Not the special shared group that is specified in usermod. And my permissions are denied, as one might expect.

```
> id
   uid=1001(fred) gid=1001(fred) groups=1003(sharers),1001(fred)
```

Why isn't it respecting the default group that I assigned them with usermod, and how can I change it so that it assigns them that default group?

Comment: What usermod command did you use, exactly? Do you really have two groups with the same gid i.e. `gid=1001(sharers)` and `gid=1001(fred)`? Rather than subverting the Ubuntu user private group model, can I suggest keeping `sharers` as a *secondary* group for the users and instead setting the setgid bit on the shared directory? See [Is there any way to make sure that any file created in a specific folder has a certain group as owner?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/30491/is-there-any-way-to-make-sure-that-any-file-created-in-a-specific-folder-has-a-c).

Comment: Also, you should probably choose a gid for `sharers` that is **not** in the >1000 range of ordinary user gids - FYI there's already a `users` group by default (with gid=100) that doesn't get used for anything AFAIK.

Comment: Ok, the problem went away, perhaps with a reboot. It behaves normally now. But, I do think the suggestion made here and below is correct, that I shouldn't really need to set the user's default GID, I should just user the sticky permissions on the directory, to a group of which the users are members.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the GID of the users.

You need to set the directory permissions to sticky, so that every file created under it, will be owned and writeable by that group by default.

```
sudo chown root.sharers /path/to/directory
sudo chmod g+sw /path/to/directory
```

Comment: Indeed (and make the users members of that group, but it doesn't have to be their primary group or anything). Thanks!

Comment: I don't know - it seems like I shouldn't do that because it doesn't answer the original question? Though I do think you deserve the cred.

Comment: Well, it does answer the question. It just happens that you were trying to do the wrong thing, in order to get your desired result. :)